# Does fetch API allow Post request to run in background even when user moves to a different url?

Tags: fetch, sendbeacon

Beacon Post messages would run in background and can even send data when user moves on to a new page. Does Fetch have similar functionality? Someone said it runs in a separate background process, but I couldn't find any documentation that validates this.

Comment: A fetch request is run on the main thread like all other JavaScript — unless you explicitly call it from a Worker. But even a normal Worker isn’t going to persist after the user navigates away from the document it’s running in. It sounds like maybe you’re thinking of Service Workers?

Comment: Yes I was referring to service workers.

I also observed that XHR performs poorly on unloads compared to fetch for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Fetch is no different than XHR. It just performs better due to browser's implementation of it. There is no specification which says Fetch will perform better than XHR for POST on Unload event.